# How do I reply to a POST in my php script?

Tags: php, post

Somehow, I have a feeling my question is very straightforward and noobish, but I tried googling and couldn't figure it out. Perhaps I didn't know the right keywords.

Anyways, I have a short php script to receive POST info as below:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['info']))
    {
        echo "<strong>Post received.</strong> <br/> <br/> <strong>Name:</strong> " . $_POST['name'] . "<br/><strong>Info:</strong> " . $_POST['info'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Post not received.";
    }
?>
```

How can I have my php script send a reply to the page / client that calls it? If I want to make the POST call via, say a C# app, how can I know if the POST was successful? Can my php script that is receiving the POST send back a response?

Comment: Maybe you can use Success HTTP code http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success

Comment: A POST or GET is also a redirect taking the user to a new page. This means you can't send him anything back to that 'old' page that the form was on. So you can't send 'back' a response, only show or send it with the new page he's loading.

Comment: @Nideo: unless your on the web and use an AJAX call also the OP mentioned a client which doesn't have to be a browser (with a page) but just an app.

Comment: I realise a POST is also a redirect, and in case of a call from a webpage I can display the response on the page receiving the POST. But I wasn't sure how to send back a response if the data was posted from  a C# application to let the user know the data was successfully received.

Comment: @PeeHaa, I know, just doesn't look like he's using AJAX or the like.

Comment: @xbonez, If you're using an app or something, then `echo` is the way to go. I.e. `Usman`'s answer is good.

Comment: @Nideo: by looking at his question it could be anything and in fact is `page / client`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The response is sent to the caller only, So it doesnt matter through which channel you call a script (whether with/without parameters).

For example if you make the request via a web browser the response is shown by the browser.

If you do an AJAX call then the response is recieved in the javascript callback function.

And if as you say you call it via a C# app (via e.g. HttpWebRequest), then the responce recieved in HttpWebResponse is what you echo in your script

Answer (score 7):

You are using `echo` and its correct. Also [header()](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is used for advanced communication.

For details on how to use various HTTP 1.1 headers you may [see the link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to send back info.

Basically you are already doing it by `echo`ing some text.

Or you can send back a html page or a formatted string (e.g. JSON).